# SQLAlchemy - Filter by username and with entities

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to get the User info but only his username and password.

```
db_response = session.query(User).with_entities(User.username, User.password)

db_search_username = session.query(User).filter_by(username=username).first()
```

But I having some trouble understanding how to filter with both conditions.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass multiple arguments to `filter_by()`?

Comment: Yeah.. I only want to get the username and password of a certain user.

Comment: `session.query(User.username, User.password).filter_by(id=id).one()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using this code:

```
db_search_username = session.query(User.username, User.password).filter_by(username=username).first()
```

Is there any problem?